# DataGridView cell is null on CellLeave

Tags: c#, datagridview, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to do some text processing on the contents of the cell when the cell is left.  I have the following code, but I get the following exception when I enter any text into the cell and then leave it.

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Program.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

If I break and mousehover above `.value` it is indeed null, but I have entered data into the cell! So what gives?

```
private void dataGridView1_CellLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 3)
    {
        string entry = "";
        MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString());
        MakeTextFeet(entry);
    }
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 4)
    {
        string entry = dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
        MakeTextFeet(entry);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think problem is this method MakeTextFeet(entry)

Comment: Have you put debugger on this code?

Comment: Same problem with me - the cell in which I am leaving the row never shows value, although the value is entered. Other cells in that same row are showing the value correctly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some checks:

```
DataGridViewCell MyCell =  dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];

if (MyCell != null)
{
    if (MyCell.Value != null)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The value of a cell is in a transient state when the DataGridView CellLeave event fires. This is because DataGridView may be bound to a datasource and the change will not have been commited.

Your best option is to use the [CellValueChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged.aspx) event.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to handle CellEndEdit rather than CellLeave.

On CellLeave, an edited cell's Value property is still unchanged (i.e. null for an empty cell as you observed by breaking and inspecting Value).  On CellEndEdit, its new value has been set.

Try something like this, wherein I have tried to generally stick to your original code:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewCell cell = dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];

    if (e.ColumnIndex == 3 || e.ColumnIndex == 4)
    {
        string entry = "";
        if (cell.Value != null)
        {
            entry = cell.Value.ToString();
        }
        MessageBox.Show(entry);
        MakeTextFeet(entry);
    }
}
```

Comment: @pgfearo makes a good point.  Your choice depends on what MakeTextFeet is doing.  If it only needs to act on edits that yield changed values, handle CellValueChanged.  If it needs to act on edits regardless (e.g. to append "'" to values where necessary), handle CellEndEdit.

Comment: @Steve Wellens makes a good point too.  You will want to check whether Value is null.  Even backspacing over a previously entered value will yield a null in CellEndEdit and CellValueChanged handlers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are leaving a blank cell and trying to process its value.

when you will leave a blank cell value of following code:

```
string entry = dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
```

value in the string entry will be blank space(entry="")
and when you are processing this value further by passing it to another function[ MakeTextFeet(entry);] it is giving you error.

Solution from my point of view for this problem is>>>

put each line of code in above method also and MakeTextFeet(Entry) also in try block.

When you will write catch block leave that block empty.
Eg.

```
try
{
.
.
.
}
catch(Exception)
{
}
```

By this thing your exception will naturally get caught but since its nigligible, it will not show you.

Comment: No, he is not leaving blank cell. I have the same problem - I enter the text in cell, but in rowleave event the cell is empty. Empty cell is the one from which I am leaving the row, although I've entered the text in that cell. Other cells in same row shows text!